React Video and Track Captions for Video Player Issue
So I am having an issue with getting my captions to show when I click my captions button for my video player. I will attempt to post all of the relevant various code snippets and snapshots below.
JSContextProvider.tsx:
 import { useReducer,useEffect, useRef, ReactNode, } from 'react';
      import { JSContext, ContextProps } from './JSContext';
        
        export type KSReducerState = {
          captions: boolean;
        };
        
        const initialState: KSReducerState = {
          captions: false,
        };
        
        export type KSReducerAction =
          | { type: 'SET_CAPTIONS'; payload: boolean };
        
        
        const reducer = (
          state: JSReducerState,
          action: JSReducerAction
        ): JSReducerState => {
          switch (action.type) {
            case 'SET_CAPTIONS':
              return { ...state, captions: action.payload };
            default:
              return state;
          }
        };
        
        export const JSProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
        
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
        const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement | null>(null);
        
        
        
        }
        
        const handleKeyPress = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
        
              const tagName = document.activeElement?.tagName.toLowerCase();
        
              switch (e.key.toLowerCase()){
                case "c":
                  captionsHandler();
                  break;
                default:
                  return;
              }
            }
        
        const videoKeyDownHandler = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLVideoElement>) => {
              handleKeyPress(e as unknown as KeyboardEvent);
            };
        
        
        useEffect(() => {
              window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
            
              return () => {
                window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
              };
            }, [handleKeyPress]);
        
        
        const captionsHandler = () => {
            if (videoRef.current) {
              const captions = videoRef.current.textTracks[0];
              
              if (!captions) {
                return;
              }
          
              if (captions.mode === 'hidden') {
                captions.mode = 'showing';
              } else {
                captions.mode = 'hidden';
              }
              dispatch({ type: 'SET_CAPTIONS', payload: captions.mode === 'showing' });
            }

        const contextValue: ContextProps = {
             state,
             dispatch,
             videoRef,
             captionsHandler,
         };

        return (
       <JSContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
          {children}
       </JSContext.Provider>
             );
     }

export default JSProvider;  

JSContext.ts:
 import { createContext, createRef, } from 'react';
import { JSReducerAction, JSReducerState } from './JSContextProvider';

  export const JSContext = createContext<ContextProps>({
  state: {
    captions: false,
  },
  dispatch: () => {},
  videoRef: createRef(),
  captionsHandler: () => {},
});

VideoStyles.module.css:
.captionsBtn{
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
    filter: brightness(110%) drop-shadow(0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)) grayscale(10%);
}

VideoPlayer.tsx:
import { useJSContext } from '../../../Context/UseJSContext';
    import test5 from './Assets/test5.mp4';
    import CaptionsBtn from './Btns/CaptionsBtn';
    import classes from './VideoStyles.module.css';
    
    const VideoPlayer = () => {
      const {
        videoRef,
        pauseHandler,
        playHandler,
        state,
        videoKeyDownHandler,
        playPauseHandler,
      } = useJSContext();
    
      return (
        <div
          className={`${classes.videoContainer}`}
        >
          <img className={classes.thumbnailImg} />
          <div className={classes.videoControlsContainer}>
            <div className={classes.controls}>
              <CaptionsBtn />
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <video
            className={`${state.isTheater === true ? `${classes.theater}` : ''}`}
            src={test5}
            ref={videoRef}
            onPause={pauseHandler}
            onPlay={playHandler}
            onEnded={pauseHandler}
            onKeyDown={videoKeyDownHandler}
            onClick={() => {
              playPauseHandler();
            }}
            autoPlay={state.display === 'video'}
          >
            <track kind="captions" srcLang="en" 
             src="./Assets/PreviewImgs/Subtitles.vtt" />
          </video>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default VideoPlayer;

Subtitles.vtt:
WEBVTT

0
00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:03.000
- This is test 5, test 5.

Folder File Structure:

I suspect that it's something to do with my src file path. I console logged my captions state along with captions.mode from the videoRef.current.textTracks[0] to ensure that they are in sync. In other words, when captions.mode is hidden my captions boolean state is set to false and when captions.mode is showing my captions boolean state is set to true. Another place I suspect an error to be is with my Subtitles.vtt file. This was my first time using one and from what I found online it appears to be in the right format but I could be wrong? Any help spotting where code either needs to be subtracted, added, or altered would be greatly appreciated! For further helpful context, this was part of my attempt to take
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeNyjnneq_w&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified
which attempts to create an older version of the youtube video player using HTML/CSS/JS. I am attempting to convert this into my React Typescript project. The github for this code can be found here:
YoutubeVideoPlayerClone
